# MySQL Stored Procedure Prepared Statement (Dynamic SQL) Parameterized

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write a MySQL search function that builds a dynamic sql value and executes it via a prepared statement.  Obviously I want to pass the user input (the search word) via a parameter for security but I can't work out how to match one parameter to multiple ? marks in the query.  Probably best to show what I mean:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `WEBSITE_mainSearch`(
IN searchWordIn VARCHAR(128)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE articlesModule BIT;
SET @query = '';
SET @searchWordIn = searchWordIn;
SELECT articlesModuleEnabled INTO articlesModule FROM sys_options WHERE ID = 1;
SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'SELECT blockName AS itemName, blockPath AS seoName, blockID AS itemID, MATCH(blockName, blockBody) AGAINST (?) AS relevance, \'block\' AS itemType FROM content_blocks WHERE MATCH(blockName, blockBody) AGAINST (?)') ;
IF articlesModule = 1 THEN
    SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'UNION SELECT articleName AS itemName, seoName, articleID AS itemID, MATCH(articleName, articleBody) AGAINST (?) AS relevance, \'article\' AS itemType FROM news_articles WHERE MATCH(articleName, articleBody) AGAINST (?)') ;
END IF;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;


EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;


DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

As the number of ?s is going to be dynamically determined based on which modules are enabled, how do I know how many time to send searchWordIn as a parameter in this statement **EXECUTE stmt USING searchWordIn;**?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

The `EXECUTE` statement must be given a fixed list of arguments, so you'll have to prepare *and* execute the statement in an `IF/THEN/ELSE` block.

```
IF articlesModule = 1 THEN
    SET @query = ... UNION ...
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
ELSE
    SET @query = ...; /* no UNION */
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
END IF;
```

I don't know any way to solve this in the limited scope of MySQL stored procedure language. To me, it's another good reason not to use dynamic SQL in stored procedures.

---

Re your comments:

> I can't do the suggestion above - the system I am using has about 7 modules.

I see... you could use a [`CASE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) instead of an `IF/THEN/ELSE`, but you actually have 2<sup>7</sup> = 128 potential different cases for query strings, because I assume any of those 7 modules could either be searched or not.

An alternative that would allow you to use query parameters is to forget about using `UNION`, and instead write the procedure in such a way that runs up to 7 separate `SELECT` queries and returns all of them as **multiple result sets**. That's something that stored procedures are intended to do. But you have to write code in your PHP layer to fetch each result set in turn. That is, loop over the result sets, and within that loop, loop over the rows of the current result set.  See example at [PDO::nextRowset()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) or [mysqli::next_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php).

> I supposed I'm safe simply CONCATenating the search word in to the dynamic SQL

**No, you're not safe if you do that!** Using a query parameter in PHP to pass a string to the `CALL WEBSITE_mainSearch(?)` is useless for protecting against SQL injection, if you then  concatenate that parameter value into another string inside the procedure and do a dynamic SQL parse-and-execute. Using query parameters does not make parameter values "safe," they just separate those values from the SQL parse phase.

You're safer if you use MySQL's built-in function [QUOTE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) when concatenating the strings. `QUOTE()` does escaping of special characters, just like `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Except it's slightly different, because it also produces the single-quotes delimiting the string, like [PDO::quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) does.

```
SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'SELECT blockName AS itemName, blockPath AS seoName, 
  blockID AS itemID, MATCH(blockName, blockBody) AGAINST (',
  QUOTE(searchWordIn), ') AS relevance, \'block\' AS itemType 
  FROM content_blocks WHERE MATCH(blockName, blockBody) AGAINST (',
  QUOTE(searchWordIn),')') ;
```

---

Update: one more alternative: use `UNION` to add more subqueries, and keep count of the modules. Then use a `CASE` to execute the prepared query with a different number of parameters based on the accumulated count.

```
SET @n = 0;
IF articlesModule = 1 THEN
    SET @query = ... UNION ...
    SET @n = @n+1;
END IF;

IF newsModule = 1 THEN
    SET @query = ... UNION ...
    SET @n = @n+1;
END IF;

... and similar for the other 5 modules ...

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

CASE @n
WHEN 1:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
WHEN 2:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
WHEN 3:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
WHEN 4:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
WHEN 5:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
WHEN 6:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
WHEN 7:
    EXECUTE stmt USING @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn,
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn, 
      @searchWordIn, @searchWordIn;
END;
```

Comment: Hey Bill, many thanks for this - unfortunately I can't do the suggestion above - the system I am using has about 7 modules.  The whole reason I'm using dynamic SQL is to allow me to union whichever of those modules are active and perform a fulltext search.  The reason I'm doing it in a stored procedure is for separation - I just want to be able to give hand the database a search term from the application.

Comment: As I will be passing the search word through a sanitizing function AND via a parameterized prepared statement in PHP, I supposed I'm safe simply CONCATenating the search word in to the dynamic SQL - just doesn't seem that elegant.  :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin, Why does [`QUOTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) escape the characters "ASCII NUL" and "Control+Z"? Isn't this overkill since [MySQL strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) are bytesafe and we wouldn't have problems with the above two chars even while unescaped?

Comment: @Pacerier, read this from the manual: "Strictly speaking, MySQL requires only that backslash and the quote character used to quote the string in the query be escaped. mysql_real_escape_string() quotes the other characters to make them easier to read in log files." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Comment: @BillKarwin, Ah, good catch down there. So it looks like `mysql_real_escape_string` is not such a great function for performance afterall.

Comment: @Pacerier, I have not benchmarked `mysql_real_escape_string` versus parameterization. But the performance issue, if one exists, is secondary to security concerns. I wouldn't want you to think you can skip protecting dynamic content. You must use either escaping or parameterization or whitelisting values, or else your application will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Since only the backslash and the quote char needs escaping, it's perfectly safe to write a custom function e.g. mysql_escape_2 that does just that right?

Comment: @Pacerier, in general you should not write your own escaping function, unless you know how to account for character set differences. See [addslashes() versus mysql_real_escape_string()](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string). It's still not clear what problem you're trying to solve. Is escaping really so slow that it's a bottleneck, and you *need* to write an alternative function? I doubt it.