# how to pass value in dynamic query in MySQL inside procedure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `EventList_SP`(
in employeeId varchar(45),
in groupIdArray  text,
in skillIdArray text,
in startDate date, 
in endDate date
 )   
    SET @empID = employeeId;

    set @SQLQuery  =CONCAT( "SELECT groupId,eventId,scheduleId,description,events,eventType,scheduledDate,name,designation,image,skills,duration,status,
    CASE
        WHEN
            scheduledDate < NOW()
                AND (SELECT 
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    event_request
                WHERE
                    event_id = eventId
                        AND employee_code =",@empID,") > 0
        THEN
            1
        WHEN
            scheduledDate < NOW()
                AND (SELECT 
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    event_request
                WHERE
                    event_id = eventId
                        AND employee_code =",@empID,") = 0
        THEN
            0
        ELSE ''
    END AS hasRequested,
    (SELECT 
            actual_attendance_status_id
        FROM
            TJU.event_attendees_mapping
        WHERE
            scheduleId = event_schedule_id
                AND employee_code =",@empID,") AS attendingStatus,
    meetingRoom
FROM
    EventList_View");   
  PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLQuery;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END


call EventList_SP('TJU_741','','2,19',
```

'2016-09-30 10:30:00','2016-10-19 10:30:00')

when i call using like this then i am getting Error Error Code:

> 1054. Unknown column 'TJU_741' in 'where clause'

while i want to set Value

please tell me how to pass value in dynmic query i have to pass value `TJU_741` to `where` clasue `employee_code =",@empID,"`  but i am getting Error please tell me where am doing wrong.

Comment: whenever I do even moderately complicated prepares I always flush it out with a select stmt (and that is it) and rem out the prepare and exec and dealloc. So to start, just dump out the string. So never just plow into the bottom of it first. 9 times out of 8 it explodes.

Comment: how to pass that value in where clause just tel me @Drew

Comment: did you read what I just said? dump out the string with a select and Stop !

Comment: So it looks like this simpler one I just did, http://i.imgur.com/828knBW.jpg . When I am just starting out, the Yellow line is active, and the 3 red lines are rem'd out. That way I see what state my string is in by confirming all my concat stuff is put together well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`employee_code =",@empID,"` (x3)

So if you pass a `VARCHAR`, result will be `employee_code =TJU_ID` which is a column. Either use `'` (quotes) like `employee_code = '",@empID,"'` or, way more secure (but I don't know the how to here, see [MySQL Stored Procedure Prepared Statement (Dynamic SQL) Parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545525/mysql-stored-procedure-prepared-statement-dynamic-sql-parameterized) ), use a prepared statement.

Comment: Correct  thanx @Xenos

Comment: @DevResearch Accept it that solved (so question won't stay "unanswered")

Comment: there is one issue coming when i try to add query and clause then it showing Error